# How to open an excel file with pywinauto on python?

Tags: python, excel, pywinauto, pyautogui

So Far, my code is:

```
from pywinauto import *
app = Application().start(r"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\EXCEL.exe")
dlg = app.Excel
app = Application().connect(path=r"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\EXCEL.exe")
dlg = app.Excel
```

But I can't Open a file!!

Any help would be apreciated!!

P.S I am using the gui so I can use an excel extension

Comment: What is your end goal? Perform GUI tests for Excel extension? Or just automate some standard steps?

Comment: In many cases pywinauto is an overkill. There are many modules reading .xls(x) files format without GUI (and not only on Windows). Anyway you have to use Application(backend=“uia”) for all MS Office products. Default backend=“win32” can’t see all the elements in the hierarchy.

Comment: I am trying to use excel with a extension

Answer (score 2):

I open a file this way (don't forget to put "r" before both strings if you use single "\")

```
from pywinauto import Application

program_path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.exe"
file_path    = r"C:\file.xlsx"

app = Application().start(r'{} "{}"'.format(program_path, file_path))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to open an Excel program using Pywinauto, you can use this snippet codes as followed:

```
from pywinauto import Application

app = Application(backend="uia")
app.start(r"C:/Program Files/Microsoft Office/root/Office16/EXCEL.exe")
```